# Error message when an SSIS package runs that is scheduled to run as a SQL Server Agent job: "An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005"

Tags: ssis, oledb

I am receiving the following error in SSIS "An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005" for each of my data flow tasks.

When I set 'delay validation' to 'True' for all data flow tasks and execute my packages the integration works okay.

However the SQL agent job doesn't run.

As far as I can tell, the reason for this is due to the 'to_update' temporary tables I have set up to act as a middle man. The Microsoft article below seems to back this up.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/error-message-when-an-ssis-package-runs-that-is-scheduled-to-run-as-a-sql-server-agent-job-an-ole-db-error-has-occurred-error-code-0x80004005-6a687a1f-917a-d3ae-4d3a-44e7dae82988

As the article says my next step would be to 'change the permissions for the Temp directory of the SQL Server Agent Service startup account. Grant the Read permission and the Write permission to the SQL Server 2005 Agent proxy account for this directory.' however I honestly have no idea where I would do this (I'm new to the world of SSIS!)

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some more time it looked like the issue was actually related to disk space, the memory on the server I was using was running at 100% and the SQL agent jobs were running but very slowly and never actually ran successfully. I ended several processes and staggered when each of the SQL jobs run so they do not all trigger at once, and these are running successfully again.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to take into account, the delay validation might be a red herring and nothing to do with the error or it might be that the Agent is calling an older version of the package that doesn't delay validation. So first of all make sure the package with the delay validation is deployed correctly and it is the one being run by SQL Agent.

Then, if the problem continues it could be permission or that the Temp directory is running out of space, worth checking it.

Finally, if it comes to permission problems then whoever is in charge of maintaining the DB, I'm assuming there is a DBA, should check what account is running the package from SQL Agent and make sure it has the right permissions.

another thing to check:

[image]

make sure the Run as is correct and if not running as 32 bit try it or viceversa.

Comment: Thank  you for your help. I've tried all of the above but the SQL agent jobs are still not running. Very strange as they run for C sharp packages, but not SSIS.

Comment: another thing to check is in the configuration tab of the SQL Agent job. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I've tried with and without the 32 bit ticked and it still does not finish running. It starts running, and executes but does not finish the job. It previously took just a few minutes when my predecessor was in post, however since they left the SSIS packages do not work. I wonder if they had permissions which I do not however I've provided myself access as db owner etc.

Comment: Is the package running as SQL Server Agent Service Account as in the picture above?

Comment: No its running under a separate account. The account is listed under credentials and referenced under 'SSIS Package Execution'. The proxy account principles are db_datareader and db_datawriter Msdb roles if this makes a difference.

Comment: Ok, but if the package is trying to access any files or folders in the network, the proxy account should also have the right permissions to access them.

Comment: I added db_ssisadmin to the proxy permissions for the account the sql agent job is running as, is this what you meant?

Comment: That will also help but what I mean is grant access to the network outside sql server. Here is a good explanation on how to do it: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/147597/how-to-grant-access-to-sql-server-agent-to-read-network-location-file

Comment: Great, thank you. After spending some more time it looked like the issue was actually related to disk space, the memory on the server I was using was running at 100% and the SQL agent jobs were running but very slowly and never actually ran successfully. I ended several processes and staggered when each of the SQL jobs run so they do not all trigger at once, and these are running successfully again. Its definitely not the issue I initially thought it would be. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear the issue is sorted!